# Many to many relationship self join SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Are there any hard and fast rules against creating a junction table out of a table's primary key?  Say I have a table with a structure similar to:
[image]

In this instance there are a list of items that can be sold together, but should be marked as dangerous.  Any one item can have multiple other items with which it is dangerous.  All of the items are uniquely identified using their itemId.  Is it OK to refer a table to itself in a many-to-many relationship?  I've seen other examples on SO, but they weren't SQL specific really.

Comment: I wouldn't say you're `creating a junction table out of a table's primary key`. To me this implies that the self-join is on the primary key, but from your description this is not the case. Instead you are returning the primary key value from rows that are joined on other criteria and this is perfectly fine. If you were to join two tables only on their primary key criteria then you should get a one to one relationship which defeats the purpose in this scenario.

Comment: @Love2Learn that's why we ask things.  Thanks for a different view of things.

Comment: Your junction table makes a lot of sense and looks like the right way to model your situation.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your concern. Why do you think it may not be ok?

Comment: I was misunderstanding the question. Yeah, I think a separate junction table makes sense, but I would use a groupID instead of itemID combinations since you'd only need one record per itemID/group combination instead of one record cross joined for each itemID combination in the group.

Comment: @jurgenreza it's a paradigm that I'm not familiar with and since I hadn't seen it before I thought I must've done something wrong! :)

Comment: In Database Design many-to-many is converted into two one-to-many. So, in your case it's the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct design for your problem, as long as your combinations can only be two-item combos.

Answer (score 0):

In database design a conceptual design that renders a relation in many-to-many form is converted into 2 one-to-many in physical design. Say for example a Student could take one or many courses and a course could have many students, so that's many to many. So, in actual design it would be a Student table, Course table then CourseTaken table that has both the primary key of Student and Course table thus creating 2 one to many relayionship. In your case altough the two tables are one and the same but you have the virtual third table to facilitate the 2 one to many relationship so that to me is still very viable approach.